# Do writes get lost in mnesia if a partition occurs?

Tags: erlang, mnesia

Specifically I am concerned with inserts. Though it would be interesting to know the answer for any writes.

I have critical system where if even a single insert gets lost then it's a problem.

Is there way to prevent this?

Comment: What's the meaning of partition here?

Comment: In the context of a distributed cluster of mnesia nodes, partition being a network partition between two nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The same code has already been written. You can get idea from source code from `"rabbit_mnesia.erl".`

I have used it directly with a little change in my project.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/download.html
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/tree/rabbitmq_v3_5_1